# salto de linea en creacion de archivo txt javascript

Tags: javascript

estoy creado un archivo txt de un listado

```
jQuery('a.descargar').click(function(){

    jQuery('a.suscription-delete').remove();

    var clase = jQuery(this).attr('data-id');
    var contenidoDeArchivo = jQuery('tr#post-'+clase+'>div').children().text();
    jQuery(this).attr('download', 'archivo.txt');
    jQuery(this).attr('href', 'data:application/octet-stream,'+ encodeURIComponent(contenidoDeArchivo));



})
```

Lo malo que me escribe todo el txt en una linea

esto es lo que intento que pinte bien

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Alguna sugerencia

Answer (score 2):

Algunas de las secuencias de escape en Javascript

```
Línea nueva:            \n
Tabulación horizontal:  \t
Tabulación vertical:    \v
Retorno de carro:       \r
```

Hay varias formas de hacerlo:

```js
var contenidoDeArchivo = '';
   contenidoDeArchivo += "Esto es un string\nque esta hecho\nen tres líneas.";
   
   console.log("contenidoDeArchivo: ");
   console.log(contenidoDeArchivo);
   console.log("");

var contenidoDeArchivo2 = '';
    contenidoDeArchivo2 +=  "Esto es un string\n\r" +
                           "que esta hecho\n\r" +
                           "en tres líneas.";
                            
console.log("contenidoDeArchivo2: ");
console.log(contenidoDeArchivo2);
console.log("");

var contenidoDeArchivo3 = '';
  contenidoDeArchivo3 =
`Esto es un string
que esta hecho
en tres líneas.`;

console.log("contenidoDeArchivo3: ");
console.log(contenidoDeArchivo3);
console.log("");

var saltoLinea = "\n\r"

var contenidoDeArchivo4 = '';
var contenidoArchivo = [
  "Esto es un string",
  "que esta hecho",
  "en tres líneas."
];

contenidoArchivo.forEach(function (contenido) {
 contenidoDeArchivo4 += contenido + saltoLinea;
})

console.log("contenidoDeArchivo4: ");
console.log(contenidoDeArchivo4);
```

Comment: considero que lo que pusiste esta bien pero si lo amplias será mejor

Comment: gracias Nelbi por la respuesta pero no se por que no me hacia el salto de linea con tu solución, al final me la hizo con contenido += '\r\n  \r\n';

Comment: @Carlos De nada, actualicé la respuesta de acuerdo a lo que comentaste. Un saludo.